# SSH RemoteForward port to remote Ubuntu is not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote, port

My local machine is mac, I am connecting to a remote Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine called mini.

Bellowing is the ~/.ssh/config section for mini

```
Host mini
    User root
    RemoteForward 8377 localhost:8377
```

I used this command to ssh to mini

```
/usr/bin/ssh -v mini
```

I already disabled the firewall with command:

```
ufw disable
```

and inside the mini, I ran command:

```
echo "hello from mini" | nc localhost 8377
```

it would hang at log

```
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 8377
```

Bellowing is the whole log:

```
➜  ~ /usr/bin/ssh -v mini
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for mini
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mini port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to mini:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jujpF3v9y4BICKUWUni22IcQ4gfZiSmmyvlgtUpoZrA
Warning: Permanently added 'mini,192.168.31.140' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EYHtlJ61GJ+TvioA3aQZqXXqomkcUmGK7W6uJmFaqYo
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EYHtlJ61GJ+TvioA3aQZqXXqomkcUmGK7W6uJmFaqYo
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/huangyingw/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EYHtlJ61GJ+TvioA3aQZqXXqomkcUmGK7W6uJmFaqYo
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to mini ([192.168.31.140]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:8377 forwarded to local address localhost:8377
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 8377, connect localhost:8377
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.4.6
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-55-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

18 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
Last login: Fri Jun 11 23:08:36 2021 from 192.168.31.147
➜  ~ echo "hello from mini" | nc localhost 8377
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 8377, originator 127.0.0.1 port 41210
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:8377) in progress, fd=11
debug1: channel 1: new [127.0.0.1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 8377
```

Comment: As far as SSH tunneling is concerned, are you trying to forward or reverse connection?

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi not fully understand ur question. I am trying to forward the remote(ubuntu) port into my local(mac) port.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the entries that you made in `~/.ssh/config` on mini ubuntu. You can safely get rid of those entries.
To forward TCP port 8377 from a remote host (mini ubuntu) to 8377 on your localhost (mac laptop), execute the following command from mac laptop:

```
$ ssh -fnN -L 8377:localhost:8377 user@mini
```

where `-fnN` will send ssh to background with no TTY,  `-L` will forward port to localhost, `user@mini` is user account and hostname/IP address to mini ubuntu.

Then you can execute the netcat command on mini ubuntu

```
$ echo "hello from mini" | nc localhost 8377
```

PS: No need to disable firewall on mini ubuntu, as long SSH service is accessible, which is always the case by default.

Comment: if "hello from mini" arrived/received at the mac's port 8377, how could I "copy" that string from local(mac) port to clipboard? My current plan is to use clipper service to listen, but when this service is running, the "ssh -fnN -L 8377" would fail, saying "address in use"

Comment: my real goal is copy the string "hello from remote mini" to my local mac's clipboard. while I don't like solution like echo "hello" | ssh mac pbcopy....For it is harding coding the destination "mac".